# Complexity of finding the cheapest path with length constraint

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization

> Given a directed Graph $G=(V,A)$ where $V$ is the set of vertices and
> $A$ is the set of arcs with corresponding positive costs $c_{i,j}$,
> find the cheapest path $p$ from a given vertex $s\in V$ to a given
> vertex $t \in V$ such that the path $p$ contains at most
> $H\in\mathbb{N}$ arcs.

Is this problem NP-hard?
If yes, how does the reduction look like?

My thoughts so far:

If $|V|=n$, an upper bound for the number of paths originating at vertex s with length at most $H$ is $n^H$. Then we can check for each of those paths, if there is a subpath $p'\subseteq p$ such that $p'$ ends in vertex t and choose the one with minimum cost. Therefore, the whole procedure can be done in $\mathcal{O}(Hn^H)$.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889418/constrained-shortest-path-dijkstra/3327906#3327906)

Comment: It's not totally clear for me yet, how your algorithm would work. So the first part would be to create a layered graph, where we mark the levels starting at level 0 at the root. This can be done by a BFS in polynomial time. How to proceed from that @RobPratt?

Comment: Once you have constructed the layered graph, the problem is to find a shortest path in a directed acyclic graph, and you can use BFS for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not NP-Hard. For each vertex $y$, let $N(y)$ be the set of vertices $u$ such that $uy$ is an arc in $G$. Then the cheapest path $C(y,k+1)$ from $s$ to $y$ with at most $k+1$ arcs satisfies

$$C(y,k+1)=\min_{u \in N(y)} [C(u,k)+c(uy)].$$

The length of the longest path is at most $n$. So if each vertex $y$ can keep track of $C(y,k)$ for $k=1,....,n$ then this leads to a polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, this answer will work for me. So in worst case this should be a $\mathcal{O}(kn^2)$ algorithm. Because we iterate from 1 to $k$ and in every iteration we find the $C(y,k)$ for every vertex $y$ by evaluating the minimum for all the neighbours of $y$.